# How to dynamically create horizontal scrollable Gridview inside verticallly scollable page at Runtime

Tags: c#, windows, gridview, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I want to create a page like Android playstore  in which i have to create multiple horizontal scrollable Gridviews on the basis of data at runtime. As i am new to windows phone development i don't know how to create it dynamically. So Please provide any type of help or tutorial regarding this.

I have implemented the below code with this code i am able to produce the required result but the gridview items **are not stacked horizontally**.I want to make the **items scroll horizontally** So please provide any help with which required result can be achieved.I am attaching a screenshot for reference.

```
 public void DesignUi()
        {
            GridViewItem grdItem = new GridViewItem();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                string backgroundColor = string.Empty;


                StackPanel staParent = new StackPanel();

                #region Header
                StackPanel headerStack = new StackPanel(); 

                headerStack.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
                TextBlock textHeader = new TextBlock();

                textHeader.Text = "Header  :-" + i;

                headerStack.Children.Add(textHeader);
                #endregion

                #region Body
                StackPanel staBody = new StackPanel(); 
                staBody.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

                #region Create Grid View
                GridView grd = new GridView();
                grd.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Disabled);
                grd.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollModeProperty, ScrollMode.Enabled);

                ItemsPanelTemplate itmPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
                VirtualizingStackPanel vrStack = new VirtualizingStackPanel();
                vrStack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                TextBlock textQ = new TextBlock();
                textQ.Text = "";
                vrStack.Children.Add(textQ);

                itmPanel.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty, true);

                itmPanel.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
                itmPanel.SetValue(ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
                ItemsControl itmCntrl = new ItemsControl();
                itmCntrl.Items.Add(vrStack);

                #region Create Gridview Items
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    grdItem = new GridViewItem();
                    grdItem.Width = 100;
                    grdItem.Height = 150;
                    grdItem.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    grdItem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    TextBlock textGrd = new TextBlock();
                    textGrd.Text = "Item :-" + j;
                    grdItem.Content = textGrd;
                    grd.Items.Add(grdItem);
                }
                #endregion

                #endregion

                staBody.Children.Add(grd);
                #endregion

                staParent.Children.Add(headerStack);
                staParent.Children.Add(staBody);

                staLists.Children.Add(staParent);
            }
        }
```

[Current Result Screenshot with the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTRBy.png):---
[Required Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSNts.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put this as an answer because the comment section was too limiting for this. So I better answer this and guide you towards the correct approach

---

OKay! there are better ways to do this. The best way and the easiest  is via DataBinding. It'll reduce your code to almost nothing, and it'll be easier for you to design your GridView in XAML rather than doing it via c#. if you are not familiar with the concept of data binding and you want to implement it the way you're doing it now then I'll add to your solution that, the GridView would stack horizontally by setting the `ItemsWrapGrid.Orientation` property of your `gridview` to vertical to stack your elements horizontally and remember to set the scroll mode to horizontal too.

For the scroll mode: add the below to your `GridView` XAML

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```

For setting the ItemsWrapGrid Orientation Property:

```
string template =
                "<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"><ItemsWrapGrid VerticalAlignment = \"Top\" "
                + " ItemWidth = \""
                + itemWidth
                + "\" Orientation = \"Vertical\"/></ItemsPanelTemplate> ";
yourgridview.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Load(template);
```

---

**Please Note:**
The Better and cleaner way to achieve this would be via DataBinding, The Below is the code for achieving this via DataBinding:

### The XAML

```
<GridView Name="ViewView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AllAppsTileData}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding AppsToShow}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>  <--Change this to Horizontal for vertically wrapping the items-->
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </GridView>
```

**The DataTemplate** 
To be defined in your `<Page.Resources>`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AllAppsTileData">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding AppImage}"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.3"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppName}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Your backing app class**

```
public class AppDataClass
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    public string AppImage { get; set; } //The image would be something like ms-appx:///Assets/LOGO.png
}
```

---

Now that you have your architecture ready, there are two ways you can go about it from here,

1. You `bind` the `ItemsSource` property of the `GridView` to an `ObservableCollection<AppDataClass>` which can be populated by your code behind or preferably a `ViewModel` using the `MVVM` approach and each time the `ObservableCollection<AppDataClass>` changes, it raises the `RasiePropertyChanged` event from the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the view automatically updates itself. This is a highly recommended approach as it keeps your UI and Business Logic on two different threads and either one of them would not interact with each other, they'll get the data via the `ViewModel`, this is the MVVM approach for more information on it use [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)
2. As you explained that you're new to the Phone development, I would say forget all about the 1st point because it can be tough to grasp if you're new to the platform, what i'll recommend is the easy way, 
   From your code behind get the data into a List something like this,

   `List<AppDataClass> MyEntireData = new List<AppDataClass>();

   MyEntireData = GetData();` 
   where the GetData method is returning you a `List<AppDataClass>` and now simply after the `MyEntireData` is not empty or it's count is > 0 use, `ViewView.ItemsSource = MyEntireData;`
   And you'll have a much more organized code which provides you the store way kinda layout.

> And in future if you want to change the way the Tiles look you don't need to wrap your head to the c# generated XAML, you just need to modify the `DataTemplate`.

If there is anything do let me know in the comments section.